# Categorical Cross Entropy does not minimize the loss?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I need some suggestion about my implementation of CategoricalCrossEntropy, which I used in my Toy Deep Learning Library. The problem is that, the loss keeps increasing, and got stuck at NaN.

```
class CategoricalCrossEntropy(Loss):

    def __init__(self, epsilon: float = 0.001) -> None:
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def loss(self, target: Tensor, predicted: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        return -np.sum(target * np.log(predicted + self.epsilon))

    def grad(self, target: Tensor, predicted: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        # print("PREDICTED: ",predicted)
        # print("TARGET: ", target)
        y = -(target / (predicted + self.epsilon))
        # print("RETURN VALUE: ", y)
        return y
```

Here's link to my repository if you want to know details of this library. Please help.
https://github.com/joshiprashanthd/neural_network/tree/master/deep_learning_library

Comment: It may be naive, but in the grad is no sum. Should there be one?

Answer (score 0):

You have done a mistake while computing graidents, you have droped the sum which a mistake. However it don't explain why your loss increases, you must have some other error in your optimizer, or maybe when you are printing the evolution of the loss function